# How to uninstall complete NVM in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, nvm

Since my nvm is giving me access denied and status as 1. even after run as administrator in window cmd. I wanted to reinstall nvm as administrator. But not able to uninstall the nvm.

Comment: have you installed it using Chocolaty ?

Comment: To do the same thing in linux, just remove it with `\rm -rf ~/.nvm && \rm -rf ~/.npm && \rm -rf ~/.bower`. You should also remove the line `source ~/.nvm` from your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 31):

The clean way to uninstall would be first to uninstall all the node packages which you have installed, you can list all those packages using

```
nvm list
```

To uninstall a specific NodeJs package run

```
nvm uninstall v16.13.0
```

After you have uninstalled all the packages go to the directory

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\nvm
```

there you will see unins***.exe you can perform a clean uninstall there.

This will only work if you are or have installed all the node versions using NVM (Node Version Manager)

Answer (score 18):

In your terminal, just type the code below

```
nvm root
```

This will show the root path of nvm on your computer.In the folder you can find a *unins.exe* file. Run it. That's all.

Comment: This command is for "nvm-windows" not "nvm"

Answer (score 7):

[NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) was created by Corey Butler it is different than the actual NVM.

The latest version comes with an uninstaller but you can also [remove it manually](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/wiki#manual-installation).

Via the github wiki:

> Have a look at the installation path - `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\nvm` is the default path. In this folder you'll find `unins000.exe`. Double-click it and agree to removing NVM and all Node-versions in the following steps.

Answer (score 0):

I verified my install nvm path and tried to reinstall the `nvm.exe` file. During installation the default path was `%APPDATA%\nvm`, where I can see the uninstall nvm exe as well. Then I reinstalled the nvm successful as administrator and then I open a new cmd terminal as administrator and was able to use and install all version of Node as required.